Problem in quantum superpositions meaning in a special case
In this article, which is the theory behind Orbital Angular Momentum (OAM) mode sorter, there is the observation of the fact that if we have a superposition of two OAM modes (which are orthogonal to each other), we will have two spots in the mode sorter.
My questions comes from a case where we have two mutually unbiased basis (MUB) for OAM modes one say the basic modes and another super position of modes.

Does this mode sorting gives you the basis which your data is in? I mean, if its in the superposition base, then some of the spots are triggered if not then one. (In the ideal case)

Does this mean that a quantum super position of some OAM modes is different from electromagnetic superposition?


